# javascript implicit function variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen several examples of java script functions with parameters passed which are not located in the script but are implicitly passed in. For example:

```
function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
 }
```

Where is the "xml" defined or listed?  Where can i find a listing of other implicit parameters?

I've also seen a function with the following:

```
$("body").click(function (event) {
   // Do body action

  var target = $(event.target);
  if (target.is($("#myDiv"))) {
    // Do div action
  }
  });
```

Where is "event" coming from or listed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Javascript callback parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769110/understanding-javascript-callback-parameters)

Comment: Functions can be passed as parameters. `xml` is passed as a parameter in the code that calls your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where is the "xml" defined or listed? Where can i find a listing of other implicit parameters?

Is listed in the very function definition. When I define a function like:

```
function greet( name , greeting ){
    console.log('hi ' + name );
    console.log(greeting);
}
```

`name` and `greeting` vars are just defined within the parenthesis in the function definition. You can just call that function passing literals or variables:

```
greeting('peter' , 'have a nice day');

//or:

var name = 'Francisco';
var greeting = 'qué pasa hombre';
greet(name , greeting);
```

In the second example, `name` and `greeting` vars happen to be called exactly like the internal function parameters. That is just by case, could be too:

```
var theAame = 'Francisco';
var theGreeting = 'qué pasa hombre';
greet(theName , theGreeting);
```

And would work exactly the same. Also, in javaScript, you can just pass more parameters to a function than the parameters actually defined in the function, and access them with the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) keyword or the [ES6 spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

This is javaScript bread and butter and any search on how does arguments and parameters work in javaScript will be useful to you. However, your second question is more tricky.

You're also asking about this kind of code:

```
$("body").click(function (event) {
// Do body action

  var target = $(event.target);
  if (target.is($("#myDiv"))) {
    // Do div action
  }
 });
```

This is similar, but also is more complex. Here `$("body").click()` is a function that takes a parameter. This parameter happens to be another function. This is a feature not supported in some languages, but is pretty straightforward in javascript. You could also wrote that code this way:

```
function reactToClick (event) {
    // Do body action

    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is($("#myDiv"))) {
        // Do div action
    }
}


$("body").click( reactToClick );
```

But, who is then calling that `reactToClick` function with that `event` parameter? Well, in this case, the browser does.

Any browser has some API's to register to events -like clicks- with function callbacks, and `$.click()` is just some syntactic helper over that mechanism. Since is the browser who is ultimately calling the function, is difficult to fully understand the internals -and I must admit I don't-.

However, you can set up your own non-browser-api-dependant javaScript code that invoke callbacks, and the parameters set up and function invocations works the same way:

```
function theCallback( name , options ){

    console.log('Im a callback function fired by someCallbackRegister whenever its fire methods is called');
    console.log('my callbackRegister name is: ' + name);
    console.log('and the options provided in this call are: ' + options);
}

function someCallbackRegister( callback , registerName ){

    return {
        fire : function(options){
            callback(registerName , options );
        }
    }
}

var listener = someCallbackRegister( theCallback , 'Johhny');

listener.fire({ foo : 'bar'});
```

In this example, is the `listener` who is invoking `theCallback` after it's `fire` method call, and setting up all the parameters to that `theCallback` function properly, just like the browser manages to pass an `event` object to the callback function you pass to `$.click()`.

Hope this helps :-)

PS: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) about the javaScript event loop helped me a lot to understand how the browser api's work.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in detail!

Answer (score 2):

These variables are called *(function) parameters*. This is a common feature of most programming languages. They are defined with a function, and simply serve as variables that are defined within the function. They do not need to be defined outside of the function previously, because they exist only for the function.

I believe you're confused because they're not declared with `var` (as they shouldn't be) because you're calling them "implicit variables." However, they are not implicit; they are defined with the function.

You can find the parameters to a function by looking at the documentation for the function, if you are using a library like jQuery. For example, the `.click()` function handler is defined like:

[image: screenshot]

<sup>(If you can't see the image, it shows `.click(handler)`, where `handler` is of Type: `Function(Event eventObject)`)</sup>

As you can see, it defines the function parameter `eventObject` which you can "pass" in when you invoke a function. You can use any valid variable name to do so.

You can see [this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Parameter) for more information on parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(xml) {
}
```

Whoever invokes this myFunction will pass the details which will be saved to variable xml. It's JS language syntax - you don't need to define the type of variable here unlike Java.

Similarly, when you do this:

```
$("body").click(function (event) {

  });
```

JS internally registers a callback method whenever the body is clicked. It internally passes the event details to the function. You can do `console.log(event)` and see what all details are listed there

Comment: Thank you for your help!